# comparing values of settings.bundle toggle switch

Tags: xcode

How can I compare settings.bundle toggle switch value correctly? Toggle switch is named enableAnotherUser.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults synchronize];

if([defaults objectForKey:@"enableAnotherUser"]==1) // here i tried from 1, 0, nil, null, isEqual,... and none seem to work correctly?
    {}
else
{}
```

po in console for [defaults objectForKey:@"enableAnotherUser"] returns 1.. but ==1 in if doesn't seem to matter, the program always goes to else part. Plus this warning on comparing 1, but not on 0: comparison between pointer and integer.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@kikovi - try something like this...

```
BOOL enableAnotherUser = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"enableAnotherUser"];
if(enableAnotherUser) {
...
}
else {
...     
}
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks damn, I'm coming from c++ and I'm just not used to think this way. -.-

Comment: I'm still fairly new at Objective-C as well, having spent years in mostly VB.NET. Some C# experience made the transition a bit easier though.

Happy coding!

Comment: Absolutely works! After 2 days of searching how to retrieve data from settings bundle: THANK YOU!